# How to make div height same as sibling div's height?

Tags: html, css

[image: diagram]

I'm looking for a way to make `#items` div be the same height as `#details` div and I can't seem to be able to do this with CSS, therefore seeking for SO help.

There are also few nuances:

- `#details` height can vary depending on the content but will have a minimum height (e.g. 400px)
- `#items` can have 1 to N items, therefore scroll bar should hide if not needed (overflow-y: auto)

Comment: What if `#items` auto height is higher than `#details`?

Comment: `#items` height should never go higher than `#details` and if there are more items than it can fit then the scrollbar should show up

Answer (score 0):

try flex like that:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
}

#details {
   min-height: 400px;
}
```

note: **container** is parent of #items and #details

Comment: thank you, this does the job (partly), but when there are more items then the height of #items becomes higher than #details div and the scrollbar doesn't show up. I've created a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BukeMan/2trjv0c7/40/

Answer (score 0):

this can easily be achieved using flex,

```css
.row {
    display: flex
}

#items {
    background: red;
    width: 20%;
}

#details {
    background: blue;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="items">words</div>
  <div id="details">words wordswords words wordswordswords wordswordswords wordswordswords wordswordswords wordswordswords wordswordswords wordswordswords wordswordswords wordswords words wordswords words wordswords</div>
</div>
```